# Set SelectedValue in combobox that populated from Data Table in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Combobox in my form. This Combobox is populated with values from a table(Faculty) in the database.

I need to set the `SelectedValue` of this Combobox based on the record in another table(student). Both tables are in the same database.

I tried to set `SelectedValue` using the value getting from `student` table

```
cmbfaculty.SelectedValue = table.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

but it didn't work.

So far I was only able to populate the Combobox ,

```
    // --- populate faculty cmb ---
MySqlCommand cmdCmb = new MySqlCommand("SELECT facultyname FROM faculty;", db.getConnection());
db.openConnection();    // open connection

using (var reader = cmdCmb.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        cmbfaculty.Items.Add(reader.GetString("facultyname"));
    }
}
```

but unable to set `SelectedValue`.

```
string sQuery = "SELECT indexno,faculty FROM student WHERE indexno ='"+selected+"'";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sQuery, db.getConnection());
MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);

txtindex.Text = table.Rows[0][0].ToString();
cmbfaculty.SelectedValue = table.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

Hoping to fix the issue.

---

**EDIT:**

> Able to do that by finding the item that exactly matches the specified
>   string [`ComboBox.FindStringExact Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstringexact?view=netframework-4.8),
>
> ```
> cmbfaculty.SelectedValue = table.Rows[0][1].ToString();
> ```
>
> needed to be replaced with
>
> ```
> cmbfaculty.SelectedIndex = cmbfaculty.FindStringExact(table.Rows[0][1].ToString()) ;
> ```

Are there any other ways to archieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to do that by finding the item that exactly matches the specified string [`ComboBox.FindStringExact Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.findstringexact?view=netframework-4.8),

```
cmbfaculty.SelectedValue = table.Rows[0][1].ToString();
```

needed to be replaced with

```
cmbfaculty.SelectedIndex = cmbfaculty.FindStringExact(table.Rows[0][1].ToString()) ;
```